Review on Simla Chadasha
As a Shochet has to review his learning once every 30 days, are there any review sheets or questions (שאלות לחזרה) in order to review it properly?

Simla chadasha is the summary. It's the short way of reviewing shas/rambam/tur/by/sha

Can I get the cliffnotes on the cliffnotes? ;)

Many shechita programs have review questions on every chapter they learn, so if you know anyone who went to such a program, you can ask them.
There is also a newly retypeset Simla chadasha with the mateh Asher and loteh besimla that has review questions in the back.


